# mongoimport without dropping the data first

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I reset my database every night with a mongoimport command. Unfortunately, I understand that it *drops* the database first then fills it again.

This means that my database is being queried while half-filled. Is there a way to make the mongoimport atomic ? This would be achieved by first filling another collection, dropping the first then renaming the second.

Is that a builtin feature of mongoimport ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what behaviour you want from your nightly process.

If your nightly process is responsible for creating a **new** dataset then dropping everything first makes sense. But if your nightly process is responsible for adding to an **existing** dataset then that might suggest using `mongorestore` (without `--drop`) since `mongorestore`'s behaviour is:

> `mongorestore` can create a new database or add data to an existing database. However, mongorestore performs inserts only and does not perform updates. That is, if restoring documents to an existing database and collection and existing documents have the same value _id field as the to-be-restored documents, mongorestore will not overwrite those documents.

However, those concerns seem to be secondary to your need to import / restore into your database while it is **still in use**. I don't think either `mongoimport` or `mongorestore` are viable 'write mechanisms' for use when your database is online and available for reads. From your question, you are clearly aware that issues can arise from this but there is no Mongo feature to resolve this for you. You can either:

- Take your system offline during the `mongoimport` or `mongorestore` and then bring it backonline once that process is complete and verified
- Use `mongoimport` or `mongorestore` to create a side-by-side database and then once this database is ready switch your application to read from that database. This is a variant of a Blue/Green or A/B deployment model.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your input. I will probably disconnect the service during that time, or try building a new collection then rename it over the first manually.